# Java If user inputs an out of range choice of number = User Defined Exception JOptionPane

Tags: java

I have been struggling about this. I want to make an input using JOptionPane where if user inputs a number greater than 4. It will get the InvalidChoiceException that I made. Forgive me if this may be a duplicate but I can't seem to find an answer. Hope someone could help.

Test Class

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class RunThisSh {

    public static void main (String [] args){

        ExceptionTest c =  new ExceptionTest ();

        try {
            c.process(5); //I want to make this an INPUT in JOptionPane where if the user Enters a number greater than 4
                          // It will display an error
         //JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a Number: ");
        } catch (InvalidChoiceException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"ERROR!");
        }
    }
}
```

This is the other classes.

InvalidChoiceException Class

```
//TEST PROJECT
public class InvalidChoiceException extends Exception {

    private double choice;

    public InvalidChoiceException (double choice)
    {
        this.choice = choice;
    }
    public double getChoice()
    {
        return choice;
    }
}
```

ExceptionTest Class

```
//TEST PROJECT
public class ExceptionTest 
{

    Object process;
    public void process (double choice) throws InvalidChoiceException
    {
        if (choice > 4)
        { 
            throw new InvalidChoiceException(choice);
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: Your exception class shouldn't have a choice field and should call the super's constructor, passing in a String. You've got things wired backwards. Do go to a tutorial on exceptions.

Comment: Why not throw IllegalArgumentException, catch it and then do whatever in the catch block as opposed to creating a custom exception?

Comment: @smitty1 Because my prof told me so. It is for a case study and he didn't even teach.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you want.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class RunThisSh {

    public static void main (String [] args){

        ExceptionTest c =  new ExceptionTest ();

        try {
            c.process(5); //I want to make this an INPUT in JOptionPane where if the user Enters a number greater than 4
                          // It will display an error
        //JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a Number: ");
        } catch (InvalidChoiceException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}

//TEST PROJECT
class InvalidChoiceException extends Exception {

    public InvalidChoiceException (String message)
    {
        super(message);
    }

}

//TEST PROJECT
class ExceptionTest 
{

    public void process (double choice) throws InvalidChoiceException
    {
        if (choice > 4)
        { 
            throw new InvalidChoiceException("Invalid Choice Entered!");
        }


    }
}
```

As Hovercraft Full Of Eels mentioned in his comment above, the custom exception should have a call to super(String message).  This way you pass a message to the super class (Exception) and then retrieve it in the catch block with a call to e.getMessage();

Comment: But where could I input a number?

Comment: There are several ways to capture user input.  You could create a form using the Java Swing or AWT APIs or you could capture user input in a command window using a Scanner, for example, but this question was about using a custom exception.   I would suggest figuring out how you want to capture user input and then finding a tutorial on how to do it as that would be out of scope for this question.